# jQuery closest() isn't Working in Codecademy example

Tags: jquery, closest

I have been learning jQuery from Codecademy. I was asked to perform removeClass() method on a ".buy-now-button" element which was close to the element that triggered the event. I typed code appropriate according to me and server accepted it as correct answer but in the preview window, it was still performing on all ".buy-now-button" elements. I would appreciate if anyone could help me. Here are the files:

1) HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sole Shoes</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/styles.css'>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav>
    <div class='container'>
      <object type='image/svg+xml' data='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/jquery/audit/images/sole-logo.svg'></object>
      <div>
        <span class='menu-button'>Menu</span>
        <span class='login-button'>Login</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Nav Menu -->
  <div class='nav-menu hide'>
    <div class='container'>
      <ul>
        <li>Shoes</li>
        <li>Women's Shoes</li>
        <li>Men's Shoes</li>
        <li>Shoe Accessories</li>
        <li>Wholesale</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Twitter</li>
        <li>Facebook</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>Email</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Login Form -->
  <div class='login-form'>
    <div class='container'>
      <form>
        <h4>Username</h4>
        <input class='username' />
        <h4>Password</h4>
        <input type='password' />
        <input class='sign-in-button' type='submit' value='Sign In' />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Product Cards -->
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='product-card'>
      <div class='product-photo sole-air-ii'></div>
      <div class='product-details'>
        <h4>Sole Air II</h4>
        <div>
          <p>$35</p>
          <div class='more-details-button'>
            <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/jquery/audit/images/right-arrow.svg' />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='shoe-details'>
        <p>The ultimate in style and comfort, the Sole Air II's are great for walking and casual wearing.</p>
        <div class='size-chart'>
          <h4>Size</h4>
          <ul class='sizes'>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='buy-now-button disabled'>
          <h3>Add to cart</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class='product-card'>
      <div class='product-photo tidal-x'></div>
      <div class='product-details'>
        <h4>Tidal X</h4>
        <div>
          <p>$40</p>
          <div class='more-details-button'>
            <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/jquery/audit/images/right-arrow.svg' />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='shoe-details'>
        <p>The Tidal X's signature rubber midsole make this the perfect running shoe. With a soft mesh upper, and synthetic polymer outsole, these shoes really fly.</p>
        <div class='size-chart'>
          <h4>Size</h4>
          <ul class='sizes'>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li>13</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='buy-now-button disabled'>
          <h3>Add to cart</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class='product-card'>
      <div class='product-photo dark-sole-original'></div>
      <div class='product-details'>
        <h4>Dark Sole Original</h4>
        <div>
          <p>$60</p>
          <div class='more-details-button'>
            <img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/jquery/audit/images/right-arrow.svg' />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='shoe-details'>
        <p>Light up the night with the Dark Sole Original. Lights around the midsole activate when stomped.</p>
        <div class='size-chart'>
          <h4>Size</h4>
          <ul class='sizes'>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>10.5</li>
            <li>11</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='buy-now-button disabled'>
          <h3>Add to cart</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Shopping cart -->
  <div class='shopping-cart'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='cart'>
        <object type='image/svg+xml' data='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/jquery/audit/images/shopping-cart.svg'></object>
        <h3 class='items-qty'>1</h3>
      </div>
      <h3>Checkout</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class='container'>
      <object type='image/svg+xml' data='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/jquery/audit/images/sole-logo.svg'></object>
      <div>Contact Us</div>
    </div>
  </footer>

   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <script src='js/main.js'></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

2) CSS file:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: 0.1s; }

  body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #303030; }

  .container {
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto; }

  h3 {
    color: #C3FF00;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em; }

  h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase; }

  .disabled h3 {
    color: #535353;
    cursor: not-allowed; }

  .button-active {
    color: #C3FF00;
    background-color: #535353; }

  nav {
    background-color: #303030;
    color: #EFEFEF; }
    nav .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center; }
      nav .container object {
        width: 4.5em;
        padding: 1.2em 0.5em; }
      nav .container .login-button,
      nav .container .menu-button {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        padding: 1em 1.25em;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: pointer; }

  .nav-menu {
    background-color: #535353;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; }
    .nav-menu .container {
      padding: 1.5em;
      display: flex; }
      .nav-menu .container ul {
        list-style: none; }
        .nav-menu .container ul li {
          padding: 0.25em 2em; }
          .nav-menu .container ul li:first-child {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #C3FF00;
            letter-spacing: 0.05em; }

  .hide {
    display: none; }

  .login-form {
    background-color: #535353;
    padding: 1em 0 0;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    display: none; }
    .login-form .container {
      padding: 0 0.5em; }
    .login-form h4 {
      font-weight: 400; }
    .login-form input {
      width: calc(100% - 1em);
      border: none;
      height: 2em;
      margin: 0.5em 0;
      font-size: 1em;
      padding: 0 0.5em; }
    .login-form .sign-in-button {
      background-color: #303030;
      color: #C3FF00;
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.1em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2.5em;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      cursor: pointer; }

  .product-card {
    margin: 1em 0; }
    .product-card .dark-sole-original,
    .product-card .sole-air-ii,
    .product-card .tidal-x {
      background-size: 28em 15em;
      background-position: center;
      height: 14em;
      transition: 0.2s; }
    .product-card .sole-air-ii {
      background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/jquery/audit/images/sole-air-ii.png"); }
    .product-card .tidal-x {
      background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/jquery/audit/images/tidal-x.png"); }
    .product-card .dark-sole-original {
      background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/jquery/audit/images/dark-sole-original.png"); }
    .product-card .photo-active {
      background-size: 30.8em 16.5em;
      transition: 0.2s; }
    .product-card .product-details {
      margin-top: -5px;
      background-color: #EFEFEF;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between; }
      .product-card .product-details h4,
      .product-card .product-details p {
        padding: 0.7em 1.25em; }
      .product-card .product-details div {
        display: flex; }
      .product-card .product-details .more-details-button {
        background-color: #535353;
        padding: 0.75em 1.25em;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 1em;
        transition: 0.1s; }
        .product-card .product-details .more-details-button img {
          position: relative;
          left: 0.1em; }
        .product-card .product-details .more-details-button .rotate {
          transition: 0.1s;
          transform: rotate(90deg); }
    .product-card .shoe-details {
      display: none;
      background-color: #535353;
      color: #EFEFEF; }
      .product-card .shoe-details .active {
        background-color: #C3FF00;
        color: #303030; }
    .product-card .size-chart,
    .product-card p {
      padding: 1em 1.25em; }
      .product-card .size-chart ul,
      .product-card p ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        margin-top: 1em; }
        .product-card .size-chart ul li,
        .product-card p ul li {
          padding: 0.5em;
          background-color: #303030;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          margin-right: 2px; }
    .product-card .buy-now-button {
      background-color: #303030;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0.75em;
      cursor: pointer; }

  .shopping-cart {
    background-color: #171717;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: none;
    height: 3.5em; }
    .shopping-cart .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 1em; }
      .shopping-cart .container .cart {
        display: flex; }
        .shopping-cart .container .cart object {
          margin-right: 0.75em; }

  footer {
    color: #EFEFEF;
    background-color: #303030;
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding: 2em 0.5em; }
    footer .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between; }
      footer .container object {
        width: 4.5em; }
```

3) JS file:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    $('.shoe-details').show();

    $('.more-details-button').on('click', event => {

    });  

    $('.shoe-details li').on('click', event => {

        $(event.currentTarget).addClass('active');

        $(event.currentTarget).siblings().removeClass('active');

        $(".shoe-details").children(event.currentTarget).removeClass("disabled");

        $(event.currentTarget).closest(".shoe-details").children().removeClass("disabled");
    });

    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    $('.login-button').on('click', () => {
        $('.login-form').toggle();
        $('.login-button').toggleClass('button-active');
    });

    $('.product-photo').on('mouseenter', () => {
        $(this).addClass('photo-active');
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('photo-active');
    });

    $('.menu-button').on('click', () => {
        $('.menu-button').toggleClass('button-active');
        $('.nav-menu').toggleClass('hide');
    });
  })
```

Comment: Note that arrow functions have no implicit `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes are working fine, that's why server accepted as a correct answer.
The issues is you have added extra `removeClass()` function for all `buy-now-button` buttons. so it's removing disabled class for all buttons,

if you remove the commented line below from the event it will work smoothly. find the line below.

```
$('.shoe-details li').on('click', event => {
    $(event.currentTarget).addClass('active');
    $(event.currentTarget).siblings().removeClass('active');

    // You dont need this line
    //$(".shoe-details").children(event.currentTarget).removeClass("disabled");

    $(event.currentTarget).closest(".shoe-details").children().removeClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Thank You so much!